# Customize FlippableStackView

Tags: android, android-viewgroup, stackview, android-pagetransformer

I found [this](https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView) library  and I'm trying to customize it. What I'm trying to do is to change the swipe from left-right to right left.
This is an image of what I want.

[image]

I also found that others are trying to do the same thing, as you can read [here](https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView/issues/3).

I triend to modify the onLayout method in OrientedViewPager

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
```

but I failed because I don't understand how it works. I guess that the part that I have to modify is the one that starts here

```
// Page views. Do this once we have the right padding offsets from above.
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
```

but I don't know how to properly change the code.

In the open issue below I read that blipinsk told that the piece of code that needs changes is in StackPagerTransformer and not in the OrientedViewPager, but I also read here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html that the page transformer usually is invoked only for the animation while the page/fragment is changing.

Could you please tell me how to do? 
Where can I find a good book or tutorial on how create viewgroup, stackview and pagetransformer customized?
Thanks

EDIT 1
At the moment I used an hack that is not so good, but it works. 
I set the rotation to 180 here

```
<com.myapp.app1.flippablestackview.FlippableStackView
    android:id="@+id/flippable_stack_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:rotation="180" />
```

and the same in the content of the fragment created in the pager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/page_one_text_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:text="CONTENT" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/page_one_image_content"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:rotation="180" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I guess it isn't an elegant solution but I don't have time for a great fix at this moment.

Comment: Welp, same here - only that I need it in a vertical orientation. Do you have any comments on how you finally solved it? Did you upload something to github? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView/blob/master/FlippableStackView.gif) rotated by 180 degrees?

Comment: yes! I'm looking into the code of that library because I like the way it's implemented, but I can't realize where is it decided that the views will come from the top :/

Comment: So I guess that using the rotation parameter it wouldn't be a good solution... [This](https://github.com/Arjun-sna/android-swipecards-view?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4141) could be a suitable solution?

Comment: You can search the library that fits best [here](https://android-arsenal.com/search?page=1&q=listview+stack)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I may continue to see if I can figure out this code, otherwise I will definitely use those links. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)

```
fancyCoverFlow = new FancyCoverFlow(context);
fancyCoverFlow.setMaxRotation(45);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedAlpha(0.3f);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedSaturation(0.0f);
fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedScale(0.4f);
```

XML

```
<at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        fcf:maxRotation="45"
        fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
        fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
        fcf:unselectedScale="0.4" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but FancyCoverFlow is very different from the result that I would like... FCF is a sort of listview in which I can show all the pages of my document, what I want to obtain is the same of FlippableStackView but with a different swipe and orientation.